# Disabling datetimes on calendar using datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

Using XDSoft:Datetimepicker: I want to show the unavailable times based on if I have a reservation already made on that time. My calendar doesn't even show up because my ajax code must have some errors or Im doing something a little wrong.  I would like to make it so that based on the `date and time` of already entered reservations from the database are un-selectable in my calendar.  For example if a customer made a reservation on June 3rd 2016 at 2:00pm then no one else can make a reservation on that time for 30 mins. The 2:00pm time becomes un-selectable on June 3rd. So a different customer can click on 2:30pm on June 3rd if they wish to do so. Thank you!!

Other links to help solve the problem: [jQuery datetimepicker: disable time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451544/jquery-datetimepicker-disable-time)
and
http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

**javascriptCode for calendar and ajax:**

```js
<script>


function unavailable(date){
 dmy = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getFullyear();
 return [$.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1];
}

$(document).ready(function () {

 unavailableDates = [];
 hoursToTakeAway = [];

 $.ajax({
  url: '/preload',
  data: {'reviser_id': <%= @reviser.id %>},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

   $.each(data, function(arrID, arrValue){
    for(var d = new Date(arrValue.due_date); d.setDate(d.getDate()
     + 1)) {
     unavailableDates.push($.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-Y', d));
   }
  });
    }
 });

   jQuery('#reservation_due_date').datetimepicker({
    lang:'ru',
    format: 'd-m-Y h:i a',
    formatTime: 'h:i a',
    minDate: 0,
    validateOnBlur:false,
    
    onGenerate:function(ct,$i){
  $('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').show();
  var ind = unavailableDates.indexOf(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'));
  if(ind !== -1) {
      $('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').each(function(index){
          if(hoursToTakeAway[ind].indexOf(parseInt($(this).text())) !== -1)              {
              $(this).hide();        
          }
      });
  }
}
   });

 
});

</script>
```

**Myreservations controller:**

```rails
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController


def preload

    reviser = Reviser.find(params[:reviser_id])
    today = Date.today
    reservations = reviser.reservations.where("due_date >= ?", today, today)

    render json: reservations

end









def create 
    @reservation = current_user.reservations.create(reservation_params)

    redirect_to @reservation.reviser, notice: "You Essay has been sent Expect your essay done at the specified time!!"
end

private
def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:due_date, :price, :total, :document, :reviser_id)
end

end
```

**When I remove only the ajax and keep the rest of the code and calendar:**
[image: When removing ajax and only keeping Calendar]